# How do I run my code from php eclipse workspace

Tags: php, eclipse, wamp

I want wamp to understand that localhost should be set to be eclipse workspace folder,

so I set documentroot to be "C:\Users\TamerPc\workspace"

I save and restart WAMP, and then try to access it again then I get :

the error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80****
```

how do I fix this ?

Solution : http://tuxninja18.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/how-to-change-default-wamp-document-root-directory/

thanks all

Comment: It is all documented on the Eclipse site https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug and you also get to use XDEBUG for interactive debugging. XDEBUG should already be installed in WAMPServer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your WAMP/server is running properly, you'll need to visit the page by going to the localhost. Usually `http://localhost:8888/` should work, though your port might be set to a different number (check this on your WAMP). If that's the case, change the 8888 to whatever port you are setup on.

Comment: Or if the port is set to 80 (which is the default) you dont need to use the port number on the url

Comment: in eclipse I got the link : http://localhost/Project1/Test.php

it says invalid link and prints error page 

I need to tell wamp to make localhost at eclipse workspace

Comment: the port is set to 80 I think

Comment: Ahh, you need to make sure that your files are all within a project inside WAMP's htdocs folder - basically move your eclipse project files into the htdocs file within WAMP